# How can I get a specific word after a phrase?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, split, extract

I'm working on a dataset that has text and I want to extract a name in the text.
So its tweet_id, text columns and I want to extract name from the tweet text.

```
text.startswith('This is ') and re.match(r'[A-Z].*', text.split()[2]):
    new_names.append(text.split()[2].strip(',').strip('.'))
```

This is what I used to extract the name after "this is".

I want to extract the name that might be in the middle of the text such as after the words, "name is" and "named", how do i go about doing that?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of the data (as DataFrame constructor)

Comment: Can you provide some examples of strings you want to match against? This should be possible with the `re` module, as you've figured out already - I'm just not quite sure what your desired result is.

Comment: @JRiggles an example would be: this pooch's name is Pepper. She's a sweet lovable monster. Although she has a lot of good qualities she also pees in the house and won't stop killing birds! Because of that we gave her an 8/10. Not bad.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, this is the solution:

```
import re 

s = "This is Shahab .... my name is Shahab .... he is named Gholam"

names_regex = re.compile(r"[T|t]his\sis\s(\w+)|named\s(\w+)|name\sis\s(\w+)")
names = names_regex.findall(s)  

print(names)
```

Output:

```
[('Shahab', '', ''), ('', '', 'Shahab'), ('', 'Gholam', '')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re


text = "this pooch's name is Pepper. She's a sweet lovable monster. Although she has a lot of good qualities she also pees in the house and won't stop killing birds! Because of that we gave her an 8/10. Not bad."
m = re.search('(?<=name is\s)[A-Za-z]*', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
name = m.group(0)

print(name)
```